# C# call function when user logout or shuttdown

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send email when user logout or shutdown. There any way to call a function when user logout or shuttdown the computer on c#, i tried to detect when the user logout, but apparently the program is closed before the email is sent.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to do this that I know of is to add a shutdown script to group policy.  See [this article](http://lifehacker.com/use-group-policy-editor-to-run-scripts-when-shutting-do-980849001) for information on how to do that.

> 1. Open GPE by entering "gpedit.msc" (no quotes) into the Run dialog (Win+R).
> 2. In the left panel, select "Windows Settings" under "Computer Configuration."
> 3. Double-click "Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)" in the right panel.
> 4. Double-click "Shutdown"
> 5. Click "Add..."
>      Navigate to the folder containing the script you want to run.
> 6. Click "OK."

Even then, obviously no scripts will run if the user shuts off the computer suddenly.  If you require a high level of reliability, it would probably be better to set up a service on a server somewhere, monitor the user's computer, and send an email when it disappears from the network.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are developing an asp.net application, start with this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus(v=vs.110).aspx

Your question is very broad, honestly.